# Duplicate Key Error when trying to persist onto a empty MySQL database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently trying to move a MySQL database with Entity Framework.
To start simple I choose a small Table with only 8 rows, but when I add them to my `DbContext` and save, an error occurs saying there is a duplicate key violation.

I checked the entries and they all have unique ID's (0-7).

Here is my code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateDb();
    LoadIndustryGroups();
}

static void LoadIndustryGroups()
{
    var result = RemoteController.OpenDatabase();
    var ig = RemoteController.GetAllIndustryGroups().Result;

    foreach (var group in ig)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{group.industrygroupID} {group.Description} {group.Notes}");
    }

    using (var context = new J1939DbContext())
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        foreach (var group in ig)
        {
            context.Entry(group).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }

        context.IndustryGroups.AddRange(ig);

        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my `DbContext` looks like:

```cs
public class J1939DbContext : DbContext
{
    static readonly string connectionString = "Server=localhost; User ID=x; Password=x; Database=test_db; Port=3307";

    public DbSet<IndustryGroup> IndustryGroups { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IndustryGroup>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.industrygroupID);
            entity.Property(e => e.Notes);
            entity.Property(e => e.Description);
            entity.Property(e => e.Revised);
        });
     }
}
```

The error message is:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'IndustryGroup' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{industrygroupID: 2}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.KeyPropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property, IEnumerable`1 containingPrincipalKeys, IEnumerable`1 containingForeignKeys, Object oldValue, Object newValue)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectKeyChange(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase propertyBase, Boolean setModified)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetProperty(IPropertyBase propertyBase, Object value, Boolean isMaterialization, Boolean setModified, Boolean isCascadeDelete, CurrentValueType valueType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetStoreGeneratedValue(IProperty property, Object value, Boolean setModified)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ColumnModification.set_Value(Object value)
at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Update.Internal.MySqlModificationCommand.PropagateResults(RelationalDataReader relationalReader)
at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Update.Internal.MySqlModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSet(Int32 startCommandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at EfTest.Program.LoadIndustryGroups() in E:\J1939_DB\Source\EfTest\Program.cs:line 43
```

This is how the table looks in the old database and I checked that they are loaded correctly:

[image]

I tried giving them different IDs (old ID + 1000) and it actually worked. However I'm not allowed to change the data so this is no valid solution.

Comment: The error doesn't complain about duplicate keys at all. It says you tried to attach a new object to the DbContext when you had already loaded an identical object. The DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit of Work which tracks all the objects it loads for changes

Comment: Okay but im only attaching objects with unique IDs

Comment: That's not what the code does at all. It loads all IndustryGroup objects and then tries to add them back without changes. That *should* result in duplicate errors, because the IDs already exist. What's the point of it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos RemoteController.GetAllIndustryGroups() loads the IndustryGroups from a different database and the context is connected to an other database. So I am loading them from one database and saving them to another one.

Comment: If this is so, what's the point of this `context.Entry(group).State = EntityState.Detached;`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla That is a fix I found online that didnt help. I forgot to take it out again

Comment: I can only explain the error by assuming that `ig` *does* contain duplicate entries. You have a new context instance, so it can't contain any data in its change tracker yet.

Comment: Yes, I can't explain it either, but I checked multiple times and the list has no duplicates

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of Entity Framework is to consider like IDENTITY (autoincrement column), an INT type property whose name ends in "Id", so we are assuming that YOU HAVE DISABLED IT (for example issuing "SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON" on your SQL table, or using some key annotation in your classes). And now you want to insert 8 rows which have the **industrygroupID** column **already set**. Assuming it, probably after the first time, every time you run your code, WITHOUT CLEARING ENTITY FRAMEWORK DATABASE FIRST, **you try to insert again the same range of 8 rows** whose industrygroupID values (which you defined like PK also) already exists in EF db.

So, the first thing is to use:

```
context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

to delete and create again your EF db.

And, I think the right thing to consider is to let EF manage the Autoincrement PK (industrygroupID). So when you insert the rows, they must have **industrygroupID property set to 0**.

PS. Detaching the entities here doesn't help.

Comment: Sadly this didn't help. Im also not allowed to modify the data (let EF handle the autoincrement)

Comment: No. EF is not handling the autoincrement, because when your code executes: `foreach (var group in ig)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{group.industrygroupID} {group.Description} {group.Notes}");
    }` your entities already have an ID, before being added to the context. You should set these IDs to **0** (`group.industrygroupID=0`) before adding them.

Comment: I know that EF doesnt handle the auto increment and I dont wan't (not allowed) to let it handle it. The IDs need to stay the way they are

Comment: Then you can try to add `entity.Property(e => e.industrygroupID).ValueGeneratedNever();` to your **OnModelCreating** method.